# Laravel5 artisan route:list produces syntax error in terminal: unexpected '}' expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

While running **php artisan route:list** via the command prompt, I'm getting the  syntax error.

My routes file::

```
Route::get('/', 'FrontendController@index');

Route::auth();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function()
{
    Route::get('/backend', 'BackendController@index');

    Route::resource('/backend/articles','ArticlesController');
    Route::resource('/backend/categories', 'CategoriesController');
    Route::resource('/backend/tags', 'TagsController');
    Route::resource('/backend/users','UsersController');
});
```

I see no error here. Please help.

Comment: It may not be in routes.php but it could be in some other class. Check all your controller files.

Comment: Yes, it has to be in one of the files. I checked controllers, config files, service providers and modals and my IDE shows no PHP error. Still checking...

Comment: See laravel.log in storage/logs

Comment: KmasterYC, that solved the problem. Of course, Laravel logs the console errors too, I'll remember that. Thanks.

Comment: Eventually the problem lies in some other controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in `routes.php`, it's somewhere else (`routes.php` looks ok). If you try to run some other `php artisan` commands, you will still get same error.

So, to fix the error, look for it in the last code you've added. If you're using version control, use it.